# How will account name-squatting be prevented?

Tags: accounts, naming

> Due to the potential high-value of certain names, we believe that the EOSIO system should offer a dynamic pricing model for account names. Furthermore, the ability to namespace accounts such as *.com can provide an extra layer of security for users and/or groups.
>
> Due to the limited development time between now and the release of version 1.0 of the EOSIO software, we are going to recommend that all account names be forced to 12 characters and not contain any ‘.’ characters. The community can then upgrade the system contract (without hard fork) **once a viable pricing and anti-name-squatting policy is identified**. We will likely provide a model similar to BitShares where account names are priced by length and character content.

How will anti-name squatting be effectively enforced/implemented?

[Dawn 4.0 release announcement](https://medium.com/@bytemaster/introducing-eosio-dawn-4-0-f738c552879)

UPDATE: [Quality Name Distribution & Namespaces](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/3189)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It won't.

I spoke with Dan about this recently and there is no intention to prevent name squatting.

However, you cannot use a name to defraud someone so your squatting might be speculative but it cannot be fraudulent, or you'll be taken to Arbitration for violating the Constitution.

Details of the naming rules are here:
https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/3189

Comment: Do you mean "no intention to prevent squatting?"

Comment: Yes. The code is written in a way that permits squatting. Any countermeasure would need to be at the semantic level (the level of human meaning), not the syntactic level (the level of code). Thus it is up to the human operators of the chain (i.e. ultimately the token holders, working via the BPs) to allow or prevent.